# WildFly error when deploy ear

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly

When I try to deploy the ear project, it gives me an error.

Here is the log-wildfly 8.0.0.Beta1 server.

I've tried various forms of resolution but can not find a resolution to the problem.

Could one help me?

```
13:21:26,674 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTWeb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTWeb.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "EEDemo-EXTWeb.war" of deployment "EEDemo-EXT.ear"  
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]  
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1944) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]  
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1877) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.demo.web.servlet.AsyncServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.EEDemo-EXT.ear.EEDemo-EXTWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader  
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)  
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)  
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]  
  ... 5 more  
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LManagedExecutorService;  
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2570) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1903) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]  
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]  
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]  
  ... 10 more  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ManagedExecutorService from [Module "deployment.EEDemo-EXT.ear.EEDemo-EXTWeb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]  
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]  
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]  
  ... 15 more  


13:21:26,737 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "EEDemo-EXT.ear")]) - failure description: {  
    "JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EEDemo-EXT.ear\".\"EEDemo-EXTWeb.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EEDemo-EXT.ear\".\"EEDemo-EXTWeb.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"EEDemo-EXTWeb.war\" of deployment \"EEDemo-EXT.ear\"  
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.demo.web.servlet.AsyncServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.EEDemo-EXT.ear.EEDemo-EXTWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader  
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LManagedExecutorService;  
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ManagedExecutorService from [Module \"deployment.EEDemo-EXT.ear.EEDemo-EXTWeb.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},  
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [  
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"EEDemo-EXT.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"EEDemo-EXT.ear\".beanmanager]",  
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"EEDemo-EXT.ear/EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar#primary\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDS]"  
    ]  
}  
13:21:26,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "EEDemo-EXT.ear" (runtime-name : "EEDemo-EXT.ear")  
13:21:26,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report  
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:  
      service jboss.deployment.unit."EEDemo-EXT.ear".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."EEDemo-EXT.ear".weld.weldClassIntrospector]   
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear/EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar#primary".__FIRST_PHASE__]   
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTWeb.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTWeb.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "EEDemo-EXTWeb.war" of deployment "EEDemo-EXT.ear"  


13:21:27,049 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management  
13:21:27,049 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990  
13:21:27,060 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.0.0.Beta1 "WildFly" started (with errors) in 4024ms - Started 300 of 343 services (7 services failed or missing dependencies, 83 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)  
13:21:27,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar) in 6ms  
13:21:27,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXTConnector.rar) in 6ms  
13:21:27,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXTWeb.war) in 10ms  
13:21:27,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXTClient.jar) in 11ms  
13:21:27,077 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EEDemo-EXT.ear (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXT.ear) in 12ms  
13:21:27,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "EEDemo-EXT.ear" (runtime-name: "EEDemo-EXT.ear")  
13:21:27,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report  
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:  
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.EEDemo-EXT.EEDemo-EXTClient (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTClient.jar".INSTALL]   
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module.EEDemo-EXT.EEDemo-EXTConnector (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTConnector.rar".INSTALL]   
      service jboss.persistenceunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear/EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar#primary".__FIRST_PHASE__ (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar".POST_MODULE]   
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTWeb.war".POST_MODULE  


13:21:32,062 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found EEDemo-EXT.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called EEDemo-EXT.ear.dodeploy
```

Comment: I wonder why the ClassNotFoundException complains about the missing class ManagedExecutorService instead of javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService.

Comment: Is your Wildfly blocked by a firewall?

Comment: No, Wildfly is not blocked by the firewall.